# Kendo ui custom validation not calling create method in Angularjs application

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I am new in angularjs with kendoui field. I have add custom validation to check name is already exist or not from grid datasource before putting custom validation every method is working perfectly but after putting custom validation custom validation is checking duplicate data and display error message.

But for new rolename which does not exists in database. I am writing return true in validation method but is does not call create method of webapi. I check my code I does not find any error why create method is not calling.

```
 <div id="grid"></div>
    <script>
        var remoteDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "http://localhost:8742/api/foo",
                    dataType: "json"
                },
                create: {
                    url: "http://localhost:8742/api/foo",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST"

                },
                update: {
                    url: "http://localhost:8742/api/foo",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "PUT"
                },
                destroy: {
                    url: "http://localhost:8742/api/foo",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "DELETE"
                }
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "Id",
                    fields: {
                        Id: { editable: false, type: "number" },
                        Name: {
                            validation: {
                                required: true,
                                customValidation: function (input) {

                                   var data = remoteDataSource.data();
                                    if (input.is("[name='Name']") && input.val() != "") {
                                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                                            if (val == data[i].Name) {
                                                dup = data[i].Name;
                                                input.attr('data-customValidation-msg', 'Duplicate Name')
                                                return false;
                                            }

                                        }

                                    }
                                    return true;

                                }


                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });


        $('#grid').kendoGrid({
            dataSource: remoteDataSource,
            height: 500,
            toolbar: [{name:"create", text: "Create new foo"}],
            editable: "popup",
            columns: [
                    {
                        field: "Id",
                        title: "Id"
                    },
                    {
                        field: "Name",
                        title: "Name"
                    },
                    {
                        command: ["edit","destroy"]
                    }
                ]
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your customvalidation with this code.

```
customValidation: function (input) {
                                    var errorCount = 0;
                                    var data = remoteDataSource.data();
                                    input.attr('data-customValidation-msg','Duplicate Name');
                                    if (input.is("[name='Name']") && input.val() != "") {
                                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                                        {

                                            if ($.trim(input.val()) == data[i].Name)
                                            {
                                                  errorCount = 1 ;
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                  errorCount = errorCount + 1;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        if(errorCount == data.length)
                                        {
                                            return errorCount = 1;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            return errorCount = 0;
                                        }

                                    }

                                }
```